# Android InApp Billing - version not configured error, while using release

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Another Android InApp Billing question...

I got the following error:

> This version of application is not configured for billing.

, while trying to purchase a real configured managed item. I have already multiple versions released for production. They do not contain any billing code,
but I thought signing a release build from my current dev branch with the same version number and name as the last apk in store, would suit - but it don't.

What have I done on my dev branch apk:

1. added permission to manifest
2. added billing code to do a purchase with my sku
3. changed version name and number to be same as last store version
4. added managed product with same sku to dev console and activated it
5. waited 24h+
6. added my google accounts from device to alpha testers
7. added my google accounts to Gmail accounts with testing access in devC>settings>Account Details
8. build apk for release and signed it as usual with release key

What am I might be missing here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you upload changed version apk on your google play store

Comment: Changed version? I did not upload the apk which I've built from my dev branch. But it uses the same version number and code as the one, that is already uploaded and published via the store.

Comment: Did you read my question properly? :)

Comment: while trying to purchase a real configured managed item. I have already multiple versions released for production. They do not contain any billing code, but I thought signing a release build from my current dev branch with the same version number and name as the last apk in store, would suit - but it don't.


You said that you want to use a configured product in your another application with same name or version right?

Comment: Yes, I want to purchase my product (which I have configured and activated through dev console), using my app which is build for release and has the same version and number as the one that is already uploaded to store. The both apks are exactly the same, besides the billing code.

Comment: Yes you need to upload new apk including billing code which has product name.. then it will allow you to purchase else gave error :

This version of application is not configured for billing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116686/discussion-between-chirag-arora-and-jacksonf1re).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've encountered a similar bug after updating from billing v4 to v6. The app is live. The problem is that for Indian Play Store accounts, it displays 'free/month' instead of the correct amount, while EU/US users see the amount correctly. Additionally, when attempting to purchase a subscription, an error appears saying, 'This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information.' It's working fine for some accounts but not for others. Any ideas on how to resolve this? @Chirag Arora

Comment: Hey. Sorry this question is 7 years old and I don't work with this code anymore, nor can I remember what solved my problem. I upvoted chirags answer, so that might have helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps from android developer site :

To implement In-app Billing in your application, you need to do the following:

```
Add the In-app Billing library to your project.
Update your AndroidManifest.xml file.
Create a ServiceConnection and bind it to IInAppBillingService.
Send In-app Billing requests from your application to IInAppBillingService.
Handle In-app Billing responses from Google Play
```

Check 
[Inapp Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-add-aidl) Link

Publish your app in alpha for testing and then check it will works.